# Select Columns Only if String length is greater than 2

Tags: sql, t-sql

Similar Question may be asked but I am unable to find anything that fits my needs.

How can I select only columns where string length is greater than 2

This is how much has done yet.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1

WHERE (Table1.ID = @ID)
```

Or something like

```
WHERE (Table1.ID = @ID) AND (LEN(*) > 2)
```

Thank for all of your help

I have a Table, in which I have 35 columns and a User ID column, now I want to select and display information from only those columns which have > 2 string.

I Like to Select only columns which have > 2 string and the defined ID by User not the Whole Row !!

I hope I am making sense.

**Table**
 [image]

**Desired Result**

[image]

Comment: Please give an example of source data and desired results. Every row in the result needs to have the same columns.

Comment: check all column's length or particular column ?

Comment: Do you really have 35 columns named Lesson 1 to 35? You should read up on normalisation. Also it is not clear to me what the shape of the desired result is. Is it a single column containing a string? In any event this is something you should be doing in your presentation layer though if you are set on doing it in SQL you might want to look at `UNPIVOT`

Comment: OK following the update this is definitely something that should be done in the presentation layer. To do it in TSQL you would need two queries. One to identify the columns with lengths > 2 on that row then use the result of that to generate a dynamic SQL query which just selects those columns.

Comment: @MartinSmith Agree; you can actually get the column list with one query, and then something like the DevExpress PivotGrid could do all of the hard work for you. Otherwise, Joro's answer is basically the other way to do it in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GIANT EDIT**

Although I agree with @Joro's approach, I realised there is a slightly more verbose but simpler way.

I created a copy of your table and called it Lessons, but I only put 12 Lessons in it, but you can generate your query in the same way.

Using the following query (which uses [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)):

```
SELECT  'SELECT ID, ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS LessonName, 
        [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS Lesson ' +
+       'FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']) > 2 UNION' 

FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'Lesson'
AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
```

I generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 1' AS LessonName, [Lesson 1] AS Lesson  
FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 1]) > 2 UNION
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 2' AS LessonName, [Lesson 2] AS Lesson  
FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 2]) > 2 UNION
... (SQL omitted for brevity)
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 12' AS LessonName, [Lesson 12] AS Lesson  
FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 12]) > 2 UNION
```

Removing the last UNION and running the query by declaring @ID as 35 gives me:

```
|| ID || LessonName || Lesson
|| 35 || Lesson 4   || Maths
|| 35 || Lesson 9   || ICT
|| 35 || Lesson 12  || English
```

I then thought to myself, well, I could probably just pivot this using the technique above... but then I had another though - the columns we actually want are in the LessonName column, so, we could probably just run a dynamic SQL query with those column names in:

```
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + ', ','') + '[' + Lessons.LessonName + ']'

FROM ( 
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 1' AS LessonName, [Lesson 1] AS Lesson  FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 1]) > 2 UNION
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 2' AS LessonName, [Lesson 2] AS Lesson  FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 2]) > 2 UNION
...
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 12' AS LessonName, [Lesson 12] AS Lesson  FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 12]) > 2) 

AS Lessons
```

Which gives me the result `'[Lesson 4], [Lesson 9], [Lesson 12]'`

Which, in turn, you could do the following with:

```
DECLARE @QuerySQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QuerySql = 'SELECT ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR) + ' AS ID, ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID'

--Query actually looks like: SELECT 35 AS ID, [Lesson 4], [Lesson 9], [Lesson 12] 
--                           FROM Lesson WHERE ID = 35  

DECLARE @ID INT --You will already have done this above anyway really
SET @ID = 35    

EXEC sp_executeSQL @QuerySql,N'@ID int', @ID
```

Which returns:

```
|| ID || Lesson 4 || Lesson 9 || Lesson 12 
|| 35 || Maths    || ICT      || English
```

An alternative approach to using pivot functions - you can easily generate this sql once and leave it in a stored procedure.

So, to put this altogether, your usage would look like:

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 35

DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + ', ','') + '[' + Lessons.LessonName + ']' 

FROM (  
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 1' AS LessonName, [Lesson 1] AS Lesson  FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 1]) > 2 UNION 
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 2' AS LessonName, [Lesson 2] AS Lesson  FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 2]) > 2 UNION 
... 
SELECT ID, 'Lesson 35' AS LessonName, [Lesson 35] AS Lesson  FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID AND LEN([Lesson 35]) > 2)  

AS Lessons --Remember you can generate this section quite simply using information_schema.columns
           --and you don't actually need the ID or Lesson columns - just the lesson names.

DECLARE @QuerySQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @QuerySql = 'SELECT ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR) + ' AS ID, ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM Lesson WHERE ID = @ID'     

EXEC sp_executeSQL @QuerySql,N'@ID int', @ID
```

Which will give you the answer you want.

Note that pivoting the data at the GUI level (either via an Excel Pivot table or a 3rd party component like the DevExpress Pivot Grid means you can stop at the first resultset - the output of the UNION queries)

Answer (score 6):

I have not managed to to do this only with one dynamically build T-SQL statement. The following is what you should do in order to get the desire result:

Create temporary table to store the result:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
     [Id] BIGINT 
    ,[SubjectName] NVARCHAR(100)
    ,[Lesson] NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Init the temporary table with specific data:

```
SET @DynamicSQLStatement=N' INSERT INTO #DataSource ([Id],[SubjectName],[Lesson])
                            SELECT   [Id]
                                    ,[SubjectName]
                                    ,[Lesson]
                            FROM SourceTable
                            UNPIVOT 
                            (
                                [SubjectName] FOR [Lesson] IN ('+(SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT '],[' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SourceTable' AND COLUMN_NAME<>'ID' FOR XML PATH('')),3,300)+']')+')
                            ) as pvt
                            WHERE ID=35 AND LEN([SubjectName])>2'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement
```

Now, we have these records in it:

[image]

Note the "WHERE" clause which limits the result. Also, 'SourceTable' should be replaced with the name of your table. What I am doing is to get all columns of this table without the "Id" one, but you can do this without sp_exetuesql as just writing down all your columns:

```
INSERT INTO #DataSource ([Id],[SubjectName],[Lesson])
SELECT   [Id]
        ,[SubjectName]
        ,[Lesson]
FROM SourceTable
UNPIVOT 
(
    [SubjectName] FOR [Lesson] IN ([Lesson 1],[Lesson 2],[Lesson 3],...,[Lesson n])
) as pvt
WHERE ID=35 AND LEN([SubjectName])>2'
```

And this is the last one - get the result in the desire format and drop the temp table:

```
SET @DynamicSQLStatement=N' SELECT *
                            FROM #DataSource
                            PIVOT
                            (
                                MAX([SubjectName]) FOR [Lesson] IN ('+ (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT '],[' + Lesson FROM #DataSource FOR XML PATH('')),3,100)+']')+')
                            )AS ResultTable'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement

DROP TABLE #DataSource
```

And this is the final result:

[image]

I hope this make sense to you. And I am really disappointed that I could not manage to do this with only one statement. If anyone can, it will be really interesting technique to be seen.

If I were you, I would make from this code store procedure with parameters the minimum length of the text in column and user id.

Comment: +1 I was halfway through something similar when you posted your answer. There's also a good tutorial for this technique here:http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx and extending it to cover your method here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1057826-392-1.aspx#bm1058068. Nice work.